# Appending text to each line in multi-line cell

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an Excel table where the cells in a column may have multiple rows. I would like to append text to each row.

The existing column might look something like (where an extra line break is used to separate cells):

```
MN 02

LB 01
MN 11
GF 05

LB 02
GF 01

LB 05
```

I'd like to change this to something like:

```
17 MN 02

17 LB 01
17 MN 11
17 GF 05

17 LB 02
17 GF 01

17 LB 05
```

A simple append (`="17 " & A1`) would work for cells with a single row of text, but I cannot figure out how to do this for each row of text.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this?

```
="17"&SUBSTITUTE(A1,CHAR(10),CHAR(10)&"17")
```